# How can I access the call_history.db file in iPhone((including other database files)?

Tags: iphone

How can I access the call_history.db file(including other database files) ?

I hope that access call_history.db file under "@/private/var/mobile/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db" folder in iPhone.

Some people tell following this :

1. Note that the database cannot be accessed using standard SDK or API.
2. Issue is we cant connect to call_history.db by SQLite or FMDB. While opening the database it through an error : "Unable to connect database".

Please give me the solution about access to call_history.db file.

Comment: I assume this is on a jailbroken phone?

Comment: including jailbroken and normal phone.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access this database on a non jailbroken phone. There is no solution or work-around.